# How to model most recent version as default version in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, model, flask-sqlalchemy

Let's say you have these (Flask) SQLAlchemy models which model a Post and several different versions of the post, which represent different points in time. This is a one-to-many relationship between posts and versions. Each version of the post has a different number of likes, but you want to treat the most recent version as the default so that if you try to make a query referencing `Post.likes`, you're actually joining to the versions table and querying the likes from the versions table.

```
class Post(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'posts'
     post_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key = True)
     
     versions = relationship('PostVersion', back_populates = 'post')


class PostVersion(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'post_versions'
     post_version_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key = True)
     post_id = Column(ForeignKey(Post.post_id), primary_key = True)
     likes = Column(BigInteger)

     post = relationship('Post', back_populates = 'versions')
```

What kind of hybrid property expression or other method can we add to either of these models to make the following query (or something close to it) possible, not just for the likes field but or any field?

```
posts = Post.query.filter(Post.likes >= 100).all()
```

or

```
posts = Post.query.filter(Post.most_recent_version.likes > 100).all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best answer I've figured out so far. Although I'd still hopefully like to do it the way I specified in my question, that may not be possible.

```
class Post(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'posts'
     post_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key = True)

     versions = relationship('PostVersion', back_populates = 'post')

     @hybrid_property
     def most_recent_version(self):
         return self.versions[-1]


class PostVersion(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'post_versions'
     post_version_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key = True)
     post_id = Column(ForeignKey(Post.post_id), primary_key = True)
     likes = Column(BigInteger)

     post = relationship('Post', back_populates = 'versions')


     @hybrid_property
     def is_most_recent_version(self):
         return self.version_id == self.post.most_recent_version.version_id

     @is_most_recent_version.expression
     def is_most_recent_version(cls):
        max_id_per_post = db.session.query(func.max(PostVersion.version_id)).group_by(PostVersion.version_id).subquery()
        return cls.version_id.in_(max_id_per_post)
```

And that lets you run this query:

```
mr_posts = Post.query.filter(PostVersion.is_most_recent_version)
posts = mr_posts.filter(PostVersion.likes > 1).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property


class Post(base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    post_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    versions = relationship('PostVersion', back_populates='post')

    @hybrid_property
    def likes(self):
        return self.versions[-1].likes
```

I think this should work. Or I maybe miss something I didn't understand the problem correctly.

Comment: That would allow you to reference likes in the query if you added a hybrid property expression for likes below that. But I'm looking for something generalizable to any field on the most recent version without having to explicitly define it on the Post model. I just updated my question to better reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I tried it only on some dummy data. It may not get a desired result in your scenario.

you can try this code:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Post(base):
     __tablename__ = 'posts'
     post_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
     
     versions = relationship('PostVersion', back_populates='post')

     @hybrid_property
     def most_recent_version(self):
         return max(self.versions, key=lambda version: version.post_version_id)

     @most_recent_version.expression
     def most_recent_version(cls):
         return (
             select(PostVersion.likes)
             .where(PostVersion.post_id == cls.post_id)
             .order_by(PostVersion.post_version_id.desc())
             .limit(1)
             .as_scalar()
         )

#now you can run:
posts = Post.query.filter(Post.most_recent_version.likes >= 100).all()
```

if you need something more generalizable you can try this (hope I didn't mess this code up):

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Post(base):
     __tablename__ = 'posts'
     post_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
     
     versions = relationship('PostVersion', back_populates='post')
     
     @hybrid_property
     def most_recent_version(self):
         return self.versions.order_by(PostVersion.post_version_id.desc()).first()

     @most_recent_version.expression
     def most_recent_version(cls, field):
         subquery = (select(func.max(PostVersion.post_version_id).label('max_post_version_id'))
                     .where(PostVersion.post_id == cls.post_id)
                     .correlate(cls.__table__)
                     .scalar_subquery())
         return (select(getattr(PostVersion, field))
                 .where(PostVersion.post_version_id == subquery)
                 .correlate(cls.__table__)
                 .as_scalar())

     def field_from_most_recent_version(self, field):
         version = self.most_recent_version
         return getattr(version, field) if version else None

     def query_field_from_most_recent_version(self, field):
         return self.__class__.most_recent_version(field).label(field)

class PostVersion(base):
     __tablename__ = 'post_versions'
     post_version_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
     post_id = Column(ForeignKey(Post.post_id), primary_key=True)
     likes = Column(BigInteger)
     
     post = relationship('Post', back_populates='versions')
```

You can now get any field from the most recent version of a post by calling:

```py
post = session.query(Post).get(post_id)
likes = post.field_from_most_recent_version('likes')
```

or use **query_field_from_most_recent_version** and pass the field name you want to query:

```py
field_name = 'likes'
field_expr = Post.query_field_from_most_recent_version(field_name)
query = session.query(Post).filter(field_expr >= 100)
```

Comment: Interesting. This looks good, but when I try to do Post.query_field_from_most_recent_version('likes') I get: TypeError: query_field_from_most_recent_version() missing 1 required positional argument: 'field'.

Comment: change **query_field_from_most_recent_version** to `def query_field_from_most_recent_version(self, field):

    return self.__class__.most_recent_version(field).label(field)`

and you should be able to run:

`post = session.query(Post).get(post_id)
field_name = 'likes'
field_expr = post.query_field_from_most_recent_version(field_name)
query = session.query(Post).filter(field_expr >= 100)`